# boto3 s3 head_object method is returning Storage class as None

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

**Code:**

```
import boto3

s3_cli = boto3.client('s3')
object_summary = s3_cli.head_object(
        Bucket='test-cf',
        Key='RDS.template',
        VersionId='szA3ws4bH6k.rDXOEAchlh1x3OgthNEB'
    )

print('LastModified: {}'.format(object_summary.get('LastModified')))
print('StorageClass: {}'.format(object_summary.get('StorageClass')))
print('Metadata: {}'.format(object_summary.get('Metadata')))
print('ContentLength(KB): {}'.format(object_summary.get('ContentLength')/1024))
```

**Output:**

```
LastModified: 2017-06-08 09:22:43+00:00
StorageClass: None
Metadata: {}
ContentLength(KB): 15
```

Am unable to get the **StorageClass** of the key using boto3 sdk. I can see the storage class set as ***standard*** from the aws console. I have also tried using ***s3.ObjectSummary*** and also ***s3.ObjectVersion*** methods in boto3 s3 resouces, but they also returned **None**.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it is returning None. Meanwhile, use the following code to get the storage class. Let me check my version of Boto3.

```
bucket = s3.Bucket('test-cf')
for object in bucket.objects.all():
  print object.key, object.storage_class
```

Comment: Although... this is using a ListObjects response, where the API does return `STANDARD`.  The `HEAD` REST API call is different -- it has a header `x-amz-storage-class` which [*"Provides storage class information of the object. Amazon S3 returns this header for all objects except for Standard storage class objects"*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) so this would make sense, despite the boto3 docs indicating to the contrary.  The boto3 docs also don't mention that this can contain `GLACIER`, even though it can, so this could be a boto3 documentation error.

Comment: @helloV: Thanks for you response. When I was analyzing this code,I saw that *bucket.objects.all()* return a *collection of Object Summary resources*. If you perform print(object) it outputs something like `s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='test-cf', key='RDS.template')`. Here is where I am confused. If you directly get the storage class using ObjectSummary resource: `s3 = boto3.resource('s3');
object = s3.ObjectSummary('test-cf','RDS.template')`, it is returning None(for objects in STD S3). For objects in S3 IA/GLACIER, OBjectSummary returns the correct storage_class.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for your explanation. I understood now. Just as a clarification for all, `Head` API call returns storage_class information for  `STANDARD_IA` or `GLACIER` objects. For object in `STANDARD`, it return None.

Comment: The actual REST API returns nothing at all for `STANDARD` with a `HEAD` request -- the `x-amz-storage-class` is omitted from the response.  I don't know where `None` comes from, but assume boto3 must be responsible.  (Most of my S3 experience comes from using the REST APIs directly -- I don't usually use the SDKs because they tend to be "helpful" in some ways that I don't find helpful -- I prefer working closer to the wire protocol without abstraction layers, in most cases).  The REST API *does* return `STANDARD` for ListObjects, ListObjectsV2, and ListObjectVersions responses.